# Как получить следующий элемент списка в C#?

Tags: c#, list, for, next

Есть список значений, назовем его `allAccess` существуют пользователи и у каждого свой локальный список `access`. Каждый раз когда выполняется функция, нужно проверить есть ли полученное значение в списке `access` и если да, то добавить следующий из `allAccess`. При этом не забывая проверять, не "упираемся" ли мы в конец основного списка `allAccess`. Я написал это как то так:

```
// accessName получили выше
string[] arr = new string[allAccess.Count];
for (var i = 0; i < allAccess.Count; i++)
{
    arr[i] = allAccess.ElementAt(i).Key;
    if (arr[i] == accessName) 
    {
        if (!user.access.Contains(accessName))
        {
            if (arr[i] == allAccess.Last().Key) user.access.Add(arr[i]);
            else user.access.Add(arr[i+1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Почему то не добавляет в список "следующий элемент" при том что были выполнены все необходимые условия. И user.access точно имеет в себе accessName

Comment: используйте foreach (string array in arr)

Comment: @tomato-magnet-regulato как же мне тогда индекс получать и добавлять к нему +1 ?

Comment: использовать коллекцию? где за ключ будет id?

Comment: Выглядит излишне переусложнённым. По-нормальному индексы при работе со словарями и списками вообще не нужны. Опишите нормально, какую задачу вы вообще решаете? Именно какую, а не как.

Comment: @CrazyElf Есть "задачи" их названия в allAccess, когда пользователь выполняет задачу, ему нужно добавить следующую из allAccess при этом оставить возможность выполнять старые.

Comment: Ну то есть вы делаете некую очередь задач. Вот и надо сделать некий объект "очередь" и у неё методы, которые будут позволять взять задачу из неё по неким правилам. Надо просто чётко это всё осознать и расписать и сделать нормальную объектную модель. Кстати что такое `allAccess`? Если это словарь, то я вообще не понимаю, зачем вы его перебираете, если можно просто проверить `allAccess.ContainsKey[accessName]` и взять `allAccess[accessName]`